# Channel not closing after timeout in netty

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, netty

I want to close the channel when it hasn't received any data after certain seconds. I tried IdleHandler, but it isn't working. My main handler is clientHandler which extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler. This sends data in string and receives data in String format. Sometimes, I don't get the data during that time I want my channel to close after certain timeout, but currently it is waiting for the data from the server.

One more observation, When I check in the packet sender to verify for the same request. I get empty response from the server but this response is not received by my ClientHandler.

Following is the code.

```
clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch){
                    ch.pipeline()
                            .addLast(new IdleStateHandler(5, 5, 10))
                            .addLast(new MyHandler())
                            .addLast(new ClientHandler(cardIssueRequest,promise));
                }
            });
```

MyHandler:

```
public class MyHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
            if (e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
                ctx.close();
            } else if (e.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                ctx.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientHandler:

```
public  class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

    RequestModel request;
    private final Promise<String> promise;

    public ClientHandler(RequestModel request, Promise<String> promise) {
        this.request = request;
        this.promise = promise;
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Object o) {
        String response = ((ByteBuf) o).toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        log.info("Client received: " + response);
        promise.trySuccess(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext) {
        log.info("Client sent: " + request);
        channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer((request.toString()), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        channelHandlerContext.close();
        promise.setFailure(cause);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the thread dump, I found the issue was that my program was waiting in the promise statement. So, after setting timeout for the promise, my issue got solved.

```
promise.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```